# What is the best alternative for public static variables?

Tags: c#, global-variables

I've got like 50 public static variables in my app.xaml.cs file. I'm told that these are all staying in memory, slowing down the app. Is this true? If so, how do I get around it?

I'm using them for such things as changing the background and colors globally. I'm also keeping track of lists on multiple pages where it would be difficult to pass a lot of arguments.

I have not tried tuples, though. If this way does not take up a lot of memory, please let me know. I'd hate to overhaul an entire app that's already in the stores if not necessary. Thanks.

```
public static double ScreenHeight,
            ScreenWidth,
            WeatherPositionLatitude = 0.00,
            WeatherPositionLongitude = 0.00,
            WindIndicatorRotation,
            DraggedLatitude,
            DraggedLongitude,
            LastSavedLatitude,
            LastSavedLongitude,
            NewLatitude,
            NewLongitude,
            FishingAreaMapLatitude,
            FishingAreaMapLongitude,
            DeviceScreenWidth,
            DeviceScreenHeight;

        public static string DbPath = string.Empty,
            NetworkStatus,
            Units,
            WeatherPositionName,
            MapTypeString = "Hybrid View",
            AdPage = "",
            ConnectionTextColor,
            RutDate,
            BackgroundImage,
            IconColor,
            Datum,
            CompassImage = "compassfaceblue.png",
            PredictionStationName;

        public static bool TimeFormat24,
            MeasurementFormatMetric,
            AnimalCallsEnabled,
            GPSTimeout = false,
            NoRotate = false,
            ResetSlider = false,
            MapLongPress = false,
            MapAdd = false,
            WeatherError = false,
            NetworkMessage = false,
            AdjacentPage = false,
            NoNetwork,
            FlashlightOn,
            UseDegrees,
            InitialSlider,
            WeatherSiteDown = false,
            LightWater,
            TideSiteDown,
            PredictionMode = false,
            MenuGrid;

        public static TrackingLocation DeletedTrackingLocation;
        public static FishingLocation DeletedFishingLocation;
        public static FishingLog DeletedFishLogEntry;
        public static DateTimeOffset LastSavedPositionTime;
        public static int CurrentFishingAreaId, SliderValue, GpsAccurracy, RutStars;
        public static Position InitialPosition;
        public static ImageSource GridViewIcon, ListViewIcon;

        public static List<string> BadTideWaterLevelStations = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> BadTidePredictionStations = new List<string>();

        public static Color ButtonColor;
        public MasterDetailPage HomePage;
        private readonly string iconcolor;
```

Comment: "I'm told that these are all staying in memory, slowing down the app. Is this true?" Test it! Remove the variables, see if your app is faster. The result is likely "no".

Comment: `I'm told that these are all staying in memory, slowing down the app.` The first part of the statement is true. The second part, well I extremely doubt it - unless those objects are *huge*.

Comment: The general argument against `public static` (i.e. global) variables is not memory - it is maintenance and ease of debugging. A `public static` variable can be accessed from anywhere - so diagnosing issues with it can be slow. Having variables with a smaller scope (e.g. to a function, or `private` to a class) makes your life easier. As an example, if `BadTideWaterLevelStations` was `private` to your class the job of determining whether it was used in a thread-safe manner (as one example) would be much easier.

Comment: Static variables have a bunch of issues, but memory footprint is not one of them. If anything they have less footprint then every other option. They are however Global variables - once you propably use to exchange data between code pieces - and that is the one thing to **definitely** avoid:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in memory should not take up a significant amount of size.  `Static` variables are like any other variable in C#, except they never go out of scope, so the objects they reference are not disposed.  However, whenever you point each static variable to a different object or set them to `null`, any objects that no longer have any references will eventually be disposed.  Thus, the static variables probably aren't taking up a large portion of memory.  In fact, any variable set to null won't take up any size at all, save for a memory address pointing to null!

---

Looking at your code, I imagine that the memory you take up is negligible.  You have some `doubles`, which are each 8 bytes, and some `bools`, which are each 1 byte, and `strings`, which change size based on length.  All of the other variables you have won't take up any memory as long as they are empty.  It's unlikely that even with more complex objects you will exceed a few KB, which are next to nothing in terms of memory.

As for better object-oriented programming practices, it might make sense to organize your static variables into "wrapper classes" which are then instantiated and stored in the static variables instead.  That way, you can "load" and "unload" your data when you don't need it by setting the static references to `null`.  However, in this case I can't imagine that the static variables take up that much memory - and even if they do, they would really only affect performance if the computer running the code had to read/write program memory to a page file.

I hope that helps - to be honest your approach for this scenario seems totally acceptable.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. When I was told about all of my variables staying in memory, I was worried. I have several apps out in the app stores written in such a manner.